# Calculating consecutive ones

Tags: stata

I have `id` and `D`. `D` is either 1 or 0.

I want to calculate "Consecutive Ones" for each `id`.

Consecutive Ones calculates the number of consecutive 1s in `D`, in each `id`.

```
id  year    D    CO    
1   1990    1    1          
1   1991    1    2         
1   1992    0    0         
1   1993    0    0         
1   1994    1    1         
1   1995    0    0         
1   1996    1    1         
1   1997    1    2         
2   1990    1    1         
2   1991    0    0         
2   1992    0    0         
2   1993    1    1         
2   1994    1    2
2   1995    1    3
```

I made a running sum in the hope that this made be a stepping stone.

```
bysort id (year): gen runningsumD=sum(D)
```

Then I also tried

```
bysort id (year): replace CO=D[_n-1]+D if D!=0
```

But this again didn't give me what I wanted.

Comment: Your second statement is on the right lines, but how did you initialise `CO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now substantial discussion on similar problems in Stata both on Statalist and in the *Stata Journal*. It helps to know a few keywords for `search`, such as that for you **spells** or **runs** of interest are defined by consecutive values of 1.

The condition for a spell to start in this question is thus that the value of interest is 1 **and** that the previous value was 0 *or* it's the start of a panel. (The second possibility is easy to overlook in coding.) That joint condition gives you an indicator variable which is 1 at the start of a spell and O otherwise. Then what you want is to bump up that indicator while observations are in the same spell.

Here's sample code and results with your data example:

```
clear 
input id  year    D    CO    
1   1990    1    1          
1   1991    1    2         
1   1992    0    0         
1   1993    0    0         
1   1994    1    1         
1   1995    0    0         
1   1996    1    1         
1   1997    1    2         
2   1990    1    1         
2   1991    0    0         
2   1992    0    0         
2   1993    1    1         
2   1994    1    2
2   1995    1    3
end 

bysort id (year) : gen wanted = D == 1 & (_n == 1 | D[_n-1] == 0) 
by id: replace wanted = wanted[_n-1] + 1 if D == 1 & wanted == 0 

list, sepby(id) 

     +-----------------------------+
     | id   year   D   CO   wanted |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. |  1   1990   1    1        1 |
  2. |  1   1991   1    2        2 |
  3. |  1   1992   0    0        0 |
  4. |  1   1993   0    0        0 |
  5. |  1   1994   1    1        1 |
  6. |  1   1995   0    0        0 |
  7. |  1   1996   1    1        1 |
  8. |  1   1997   1    2        2 |
     |-----------------------------|
  9. |  2   1990   1    1        1 |
 10. |  2   1991   0    0        0 |
 11. |  2   1992   0    0        0 |
 12. |  2   1993   1    1        1 |
 13. |  2   1994   1    2        2 |
 14. |  2   1995   1    3        3 |
     +-----------------------------+
```

A reading and program list might include

```
SJ-15-1 dm0079  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Stata tip 123: Spell boundaries
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q1/15   SJ 15(1):319--323                                (no commands)
        shows how to identify spells

SJ-7-2  dm0029  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Speaking Stata: Identifying spells
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q2/07   SJ 7(2):249--265                                 (no commands)
        shows how to handle spells with complete control over
        spell specification
```

.pdf of last mentioned freely available at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0029

.pdf of first mentioned will become freely available on publication of *Stata Journal* 18(1).

`tsspell` (SSC) is a basic tool using the principles described in the 2007 paper just cited. `tsspell` thus gives you an otherwise unpredictable search term for searching Statalist discussions.

https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/identifying-runs-of-consecutive-observations/ is also relevant for related problems.